# People in the NYC area - want to come to a Health Tech meetup?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'm talking with [WorkSmart Labs](http://www.worksmartlabs.com/) about organizing a Health Tech Meetup, and we want to do an informal meet and greet at a bar in order to gauge interest. I think it could be really cool to start a regular Health Tech Meetup group, so I'm hoping that some of our users in the NYC area will want to participate! If you live in or near NYC, please reply to this message or email me at lauren@stackexchange.com to let me know what you think.

We're thinking about November 16th for the meet and greet, so send me your thoughts asap!

[**Edit**]: The meet and greet with Worksmart Labs and Next Jump went really well! We are planning on organizing a larger meet-up in December for our users as well as anyone on meetup.com who wants to join. I'll keep you posted on details as we work them out, but if you or someone you know lives in the NYC area and would be interested in coming, definitely let me know!